# CSS modifications are not refreshed in Symfony2, dev environment

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

This is a recurring problem but none of the proposed solutions convince me.

According to documentation, when using dev environment, modifications made to CSS's files in Resources/public/css are refreshed immediately, but they are not.

All solutions were that I need to issue a assetic:dump command but this is not the solution. If I do that, several JS and CSS files fill JS and CSS directories of the web folder, most of them repeated files. So, this is not the solution.

Currently, I have in my CSS and JS folders only CSS and JS files for production environment that are loaded when used app.php entry point.

When I use app_dev.php entry point, the site works, CSS are loaded, JS are loaded, but not the ones belonging to Resources/public folder.

CSS URL is this: http://compromisos.local/app_dev.php/css/base_style_1.css. The corresponding CSS file is style.css.

I found out that the CSS are coming from web/bundles/mybundle/css (or js) folder. So, when I change a CSS file in Resources/public folder, I need to publish assets first.

I was trying to configure assetic to use the CSS and JS rom Resources/public folder instead, but without success.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    read_from:      %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/
    write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../web/
    bundles:        [ FOSUserBundle, DesytecGestionBundle ]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I use constantly in my dev environment

My `assetic` config parameter:

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: true # set to true in config_dev.yml{1} otherwise default to false{2}
    # bundles:        [ ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

{1} [config_dev.yml](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/config/config_dev.yml#L32)
{2} [config.yml](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/config/config.yml#L30)

Then I just do:

- `php app/console assets:install`
- `php app/console assetic:dump --watch` (deprecated in 2.4, you should use: `php app/console assetic:watch`)

I also reference my file the following way:

```
{% stylesheets '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/css/style.css' %}
  <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: I have solved css problem, but a new problem occured, and it is concerning images referenced inside CSS file. When running the application in dev mode, assetic transforms images links inside CSS to be ../Resources/public/images, which of course does not exist in public web folder. How can I resolve this?

Comment: If you use the solution in my answer, then there is two ways you can handle this (probably more), either you put the images within `web/images` and reference them in the CSS via `../images/filename.extension` or you can reference the full path like `/bundles/bundlename/images/filename.extension`. When you run the command `assets:install` it will install the different assets within their respective bundle folders in `web/bundles`.

Comment: Thanks! I have finally use the first way... I have placed images in /web/images folder and referenced by url(/images/......) inside the CSS.